# Representing the generating function using binomial theorem.

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, binomial-theorem

Lets say we have a set {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, There are 32 subsets. Now if we take these subsets and arrange them according to the sum of their members; For eg:
The subset {2, 3} would be in the same group as the subset {1, 4} as the sum of their members is the same.
If we use the "Generating function" as used in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bOXCLR3Wric, We get the number of such arrangements as the coefficients of a long polynomial.

Generating function:
f(x) = $(1+x^1)(1+x^2) .... (1+x^n)$, where n is the number of elements in the set.
while expanded it forms: $1+x^1+x^2+2x^3+2x^4+3x^5+4x^6+5x^7 + ....$

Now is it possible to represent this function neatly with a single equation using Binomial theorem (Binomial coefficients?)

Comment: I am not sure, but it seems that $f(x)$ should have a product instead of a sum

Comment: No, there is no way to simplify that generating function (which indeed should be a product).

Comment: If there was a way to simplify $f(x)$, don't you think 3b1b would have employed that in their video?

Comment: In 3Blue1Brown's video, the function is actually $$f(x) = (1+x^1) \cdot  (1+x^2) \cdots  (1+x^n)$$ not a sum but a product as @stackoverload noted

Comment: sorry about the sum, it should be a product. i changed it

Answer (score 1):

Given $[n]=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ the wanted generating function is
\begin{align*}
f(x)=\prod_{j=1}^n\left(1+x^j\right)\tag{1}
\end{align*}
since each of the elements in $[n]$ is either an element of the subset under consideration or not an element.
The coefficients of $x^j$ in $f$ are for increasing $n$:
\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{lll}
n=0:&\{\emptyset\}&\color{blue}{1}\\
n=1:&\{\emptyset,\{1\}\}&\color{blue}{1,1}\\
n=2:&\{\emptyset,\{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\}\}&\color{blue}{1,1,1,1}\\
n=3:&\{\emptyset,\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{2,3\},\{1,2,3\}\}&\color{blue}{1,1,1,2,1,1,1}\\
\dots&\ldots&\ldots
\end{array}
\end{align*}
The blue marked sequence of coefficients of $x^n$ of increasing $n$ is stored in OEIS as *[A053632](http://oeis.org/A053632)*. Note, there is no other simple representation given.